# Dynamically updating MIDI sequences

Tags: java, midi

I have a program which dynamically creates sequences of midi events after some user input, and does that while looping the currently played sequence. It's written in scala and I'm using the java library `javax.sound.midi.*`

Now the algorithm works as follows:

1. create sequencer;
2. build sequence;
3. set sequence
4. start the sequencer;
5. build new sequence;
6. when the finish event is triggered by the sequencer execute from 3

the problem with this approach is that there is a delay between two sequences, while I would like it to be playing without pauses, if possible even overlapping the two sequences.

Is there any way to do it?