# Java MIDI Sequencer alternatives

Tags: java, midi

I was trying to use the MIDI sequencer incorporated into the JVM (as told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361886/dynamically-updating-midi-sequences), if anyone has an answer it's still welcome) and found that this sequencer implementations has several limitations, that range from being stuck to the Java MIDI synthesizer (I want to use the Steinberg VSTs in the future) to sensible latencies.

So I'm wondering if there are well known, recognized and working sequencer implementations for Java, as reinventing the wheel is rarely a good idea :)

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

This past weekend I wrote code using the java midi libraries for an open source coding competition. From my time spent doing it, I realized that java's midi support has been lackluster as of late in terms of flexibility and the sound classes seem to have taken a backseat in terms of support. There are however resources and third-party packages to look into that try to provide more implementation. I personally found http://jsresources.org/ as fairly useful and http://www.tritonus.org/ seems to be the 3rd-party implementation of choice. In terms of using your own synthesizers as opposed to the hardware default I don't have experience, but the two sites above are good places to start.